# Use Git's minimal diff algorithm for patch

Tags: git

I have solely deleted a ton of lines in a really large file. When I stage and commit the changes to the file, Git's default diff algorithm thinks I've moved a bunch of things around instead of only deleting lines (the file has a lot of repetitive lines).

Here's my output from two different diff algorithms:

```
git diff --stat
1 file changed, 4373 insertions(+), 9192 deletions(-)

git diff --stat --minimal
1 file changed, 4819 deletions(-)
```

Is there a way that I can enter patch mode with the `--minimal` setting so that I can separate these into multiple commits for the purpose of reducing my perceived footprint on this file?

**EDIT**: Even after all of this effort to reduce my footprint, **the diff across the multiple commits using the myers (default) algorithm *still* shows the insertions**... I was hoping this would not happen, but now it seems that I have wasted a lot of time in exchange for learning something new about Git.

Comment: Maybe it's possible, maybe not. As a fallback method, you could stash these changes and manually replay the subsets of changes that you want to commit.

Comment: I was considering that, but the only inconvenient thing about that is I would get conflicts each time I applied the stash; and as a whole, these line deletions are not contiguous at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the patch mode uses your configured default diff algorithm. Updating my config with the following command gave me the desired results.

`git config --global diff.algorithm minimal`